# Percent from decimal? PHP

Tags: php

Trying to convert this `"0.274509817"` to a nice precentage like `27%`

The string is a dynamic value from an API.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$percent = round((float)$str * 100 ) . '%';
```

Where `$str` = `"0.274509817"`

Comment: Is it necessary to have `(float)`?

Comment: No, but it makes things clear. And in case `$str == false` for whatever reason, it makes sure things don't break.

Comment: @AndrewFerrara: Since the OP wrote the vale using double-quotes, we assume it is a string. And its good practice to always typecast such cases, and do not rely on implicit conversions. And makes code easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = 0.274509817;
echo round( $number * 100 ), '%';
```

Comment: This is perfect, and so much easier ;3

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with `intval($a * 100) . '%'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
round((float)$value * 100) . '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

and after that, append

```
"&#37;"
```

to get the percent sign (e.g. if used with sprintf).

Comment: Why use ASCII code for % ? Makes code much harder to read, while '%' works perfectly

Comment: Just a suggestion in case the real code used sprintf.  I should have clarified this.  Yes, if it's just string concatenation, then adding '%' is the way to go.