# Convert a percentage into a decimal and remove percent sign in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What is the best way to move a decimal over two places and remove the percentage sign in PHP?

For example:

`9.5%` turns into `.095`

Is there a special function for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Percent from decimal? PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055387/percent-from-decimal-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the '%' is at the end, you can simply cast the string as a float and divide by 100:

```
echo (float)'9.5%'/100;
```

Output:

```
0.095
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your own function like this :

```
private function myConvertFunction($percentage)
{
    return floatval(str_replace('%', '', $percentage)) /100;
}
```

Will return

```
echo 'The result is : ' . myConvertFunction('9.5%');

The result is : 0.095
```

Comment: But this is the best way to do it? There's no built in function in PHP?

Comment: I don't think this kind of function exists... since it's kinda specific for your need. But as I showed you, this isn't really a big deal since the function is 1 line long and you can customize it as you want, with for exemple 1000 instead of 100, or if you need to remove another char from your string

Answer (score -1):

first, remove % sign from the value

```
$number = str_replace('%','',$number);
```

convert the value in the required format

```
$number = $number * 0.01;
```

Comment: Could you potentially provide more information about how this would be the correct solution? What does each line do and why?