# Decimal to Percentage conversion in PHP

Tags: php, json

Iam trying to get the score from Google Lighthouse as json. The scores are showing as 0.25, 0.77 which i wanted to show as 25% and 77% and so on. How can i do this math in PHP.

> Lighthouse returns a performance score from 0-100 (technically returned as 0-1, but you can do the math ;).

Iam a beginner in php.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055398/5413283

```
round((float)$val * 100 ) . '%';
```