# Can't figure out how to convert decimal to percentage properly

Tags: php

I have this number `0.00072731252499793` and I need to convert it to a percentage value so it returns the result of `72%` but I cannot figure out the way to do it. I tried some solutions from another threads but no luck. I always got `0%`. Is there any way to achieve this?

`my code`

```php
<?php

$number = 0.00072731252499793;
echo round( $number * 100 ) . '%'; // this gave me 0%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Percent from decimal? PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055387/percent-from-decimal-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert 0.00072731252499793 to 72, you need to multiply it with 100000 and after that round it down (floor).

so you can use:

```
<?php
$number = 0.00072731252499793;
echo floor($number * 100000) . '%';
```

What you are doing is :
You're multiplying 0.00072731252499793 with 100 which returns 0.072731252499793 and round function is converting it into 0 as you're not passing any decimal place.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 1 means 100%, then `0.00072731252499793` is `0.07..%` so when you round it it becomes zero, because default rounding rule is `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP`, and default precision (numbers after comma) is `0`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Depending on your needs, you can try to adjust precision like this

```
<?php

$number = 0.00072731252499793;
echo round( $number * 100, 2 ) . '%'; // 0.07%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$number = 0.00072731252499793;
echo round( $number * 100000 ) . '%';
```

Comment: This is risky, because decimal `0.13` would result in `13000%` . Depending on the rest of the logic in the code this might be correct, but most probably - it's wrong solution.